# Catalog + Categories + Attribute Set import / export tool

Tags: magento2, catalog, importexport

I am looking for a comprehensive import / export tool for Magento 2.0.

I have a typical development environment where there is a dev instance, a staging and production environment.

I am embarking on a set of new websites development and need a way to export / import / sync any product definitions in the catalog to the other Magento instances.

The tool must be able to create new records or update existing records.

The type of data must include the catalog (simple, virtual, grouped, and bundled products / bundle items), attribute sets, categories, attribute values, pricing, preserving default vs. website values, images, etc.

Please let me know if you know of a suitable extension or solution.